# Changing the C parameter in SVM

Tags: machine-learning, classification, svm

In SVM we can change the C parameter.

What are the advantages and disadvantages of doing so?

Comment: Normally, resampling techniques (cross-validation) are used for determine the optimal C parameter in each analysis

Comment: C is the penalization parameter controlling the errors fitted by SVM, but C is not a variable

Comment: The tuning parameter $C$ is the weight of the misclassification errors in the loss function that SVM minimises.  The loss function has two components (a) one over the width of the margin and (b) the misclassification errors, weighted by $C$.  As SVM tries to minimise this, it tries to maximise the margin + $C$ times the misclassification error. So for a very large $C$ the second components weights more and you will strive for less misclassification errors, for small $C$ minimising the misclassifications will be less important than maximising the margin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, the tuning parameter $C$ in SVM is defined as following,
$$C\sum_i^{n}\xi_i $$
As Jesus Herranz Valera mentioned, this parameter can be determined by Cross Validation.

In your model, you actually define the more general parameter C,
$$\sum_i^n C_i \xi_i $$
It means that you assign different weights to the training data, if you define $C_i = C$ those two model wii be the same.

[SVM: Weighted samples](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/svm/plot_weighted_samples.html) provides the package to train the model. If you already know which data are important to your model or the weight for your training data, this this model will be pretty useful.

Since you have n parameters, I don't think Cross-Validation can help you to determine those parameter (too many parameters). One reasonable solution is that you can define the specific weight for data and train following SVM model.
$$\sum_i^n C_i \xi_i + \lambda J(f) $$
Then using Cross Validation to determine the $\lambda$ instead of $C$. And the definition of $C$ should depend on the pattern of your datasets.